# Code-behind popup ActualHeight and ActualWidth always 0

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am creating a code-behind popup. On button click adding child and setting IsOpen = true. Now I can see the popup. 
I have another button, on click, the popup's ActualHeight (and ActualWidth) always returns 0. How can I get the actual value? 
Note : Snoop shows correct values.

Code snippet:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Popup popup = new Popup();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonShowPopup_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e1)
    {
        var dockPanel = new DockPanel();
        dockPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = "First TextBlock", Background = Brushes.White });
        popup.Child = dockPanel;
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void ButtonProperties_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate(Object state)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(popup.ActualHeight.ToString());
            return null;
        }), null);
        MessageBox.Show(popup.ActualHeight.ToString());
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Click="ButtonShowPopup_OnClick" Content="ShowPopup"></Button>
    <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="ButtonProperties_OnClick"  Content="Get Actual height &amp; Width"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Popup.Child` object.

```
...
private void ButtonProperties_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(popup.Child.RenderSize.Height.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
...
```